Docker-Desktop installed in azure pipeline build agent on Windows 10 stops without any user logged in
In on-premise Azure DevOps Server 2022, the pipeline build-agents installed in Windows 10 machine.
I have installed docker-desktop on the Windows machine to run the docker related task from the pipeline.
But Docker-Desktop stops when no user logged-in  in the Windows 10 machine.  When the pipeline always runs, docker related task fails because the docker engine on the Build machine is not running.
After I logged in to the machine and start the Docker-Desktop, the pipeline runs successfully.
Has anyone any idea how to run the docker engine always in the Windows 10 Build Machine ??
I am expecting Docker-engine always runs without user login in windows 10.

Hi there, Have you tried to configure the agent service to run as your user account not a system service account on that machine?

The agent is running as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK_SERVICE account.

I tested to install docker with the script instead of docker desktop. And the pipeline succeeded to pull image when my user account was signed out from that agent machine. My agent service was running as the local user account .\Alvin.

Instead of using Docker Desktop, we can install Docker Community Edition with the script below, as suggested in the document.
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1" -o 
install-docker-ce.ps1 .\install-docker-ce.ps1

In addition, I configured the agent service to run as the local user account. The pipeline running on this agent machine succeeded to run the docker commands even when the user signed out of the machine.


